# Script is hard to manage

Tags: javascript

I'm planning to increase the number of elements in the "source" div from two to three. But in order to increase it, I need to create a lot of new lines of code with pretty much the same data (const three, new fuction appendIt2 and add an extra if in the window.onload).

Maybe you can advise how can I reduce the clutter in this script and make it easier to edit and read?

```js
const one = document.getElementById("element");
element.addEventListener("click", appendIt);

function appendIt() {
  localStorage.setItem("append", "true");
  var element = document.getElementById("element");
  document.getElementById("destination").appendChild(element);
}

const two = document.getElementById("element1");
element1.addEventListener("click", appendIt1);

function appendIt1() {
  localStorage.setItem("append1", "true");
  var element1 = document.getElementById("element1");
  document.getElementById("destination").appendChild(element1);
}


window.onload = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("append") == "true") {
    appendIt();
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("append1") == "true") {
    appendIt1();
  }
};

function clearstorage() {
  localStorage.clear();
  location.reload();
}
```

```css
#destination {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

#source {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clearstorage()">
  Reset order
</button>
<div id="destination"></div>
<div id="source">
  <a id="element" href="#">One</a>
  <a id="element1" href="#">Two</a></div>
```

Comment: Why didn't you do a function that takes parameters if the only difference is just a couple of strings?

Comment: I would, but unfortunately, I don't know how to do it. What I have done when adding a second element is the only way I understand how to do it, by manually creating new similar formulas.

Comment: [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask a question like this.

Comment: @Etheryte, thanks. Wasn't aware of that website.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a generic function to append

```
function append(itemName, elementId) {
  localStorage.setItem(itemName, "true");
  let element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  document.getElementById("destination").appendChild(element1);
}
```

In order to use it, pass an arrow function as callback to the event listener, in this way:

```
theElement.addEventListener("click", () => append("append", "element"));
```

This would lead to:

```js
function append(itemName, elementId) {
  localStorage.setItem(itemName, "true");
  let element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  document.getElementById("destination").appendChild(element1);
}

const one = document.getElementById("element");
// Use arrow function as callback to pass the proper values to the generic append() function
// I replaced 'element' variable with 'one' here, which is the element you just retrieved
one.addEventListener("click", () => append("append", "element"));

const two = document.getElementById("element1");
two.addEventListener("click", () => append("append1", "element1"));

// When appending new child:
//    const three = document.getElementById("element2");
//    three.addEventListener("click", () => append("append2", "element2"));


window.onload = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("append") == "true") {
    append("append", "element");
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("append1") == "true") {
    append("append1", "element1")
  }
};

function clearstorage() {
  localStorage.clear();
  location.reload();
}
```

```css
#destination {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

#source {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clearstorage()">
  Reset order
</button>
<div id="destination"></div>
<div id="source">
  <a id="element" href="#">One</a>
  <a id="element1" href="#">Two</a></div>
```

If you want to go further, you could have a map like:

```
const appendToElementMap = {
  "element": "append",
  "element1": "append1"
};
```

and iterate upon its entries to add the event listeners

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep your functions in a seperate javascript file in some util folder. That folder should contain files which are serving some meaningful purpose. And, improve your naming convention also, maybe that will ease out the process a bit. It will help you in the long run.

Comment: Thank you. I have used this naming just as an example. I'm hoping that someone knows a solution that will include something like "this.element" or "index[1]" which will drastically reduce the code length. Naming and moving the functions will help, but won't resolve the issue completely.